# Error while restoring from a checkpoint in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

```
def test_neural_network():
    prediction = neural_network_model(x)
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
        for epoch in range(hm_epochs):
            saver.restore(sess, './model.ckpt')
        # more code here
```

This is a sample of the code that I am working on. I have saved the `model.ckpt` in the same directory as my file.

However when I run the code, I get an error saying:

```
InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Expected to restore a tensor of type float, got a tensor of type int32 instead: tensor_name = Variable
 [[Node: save/RestoreV2 = RestoreV2[dtypes=[DT_FLOAT], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](_recv_save/Const_0, save/RestoreV2/tensor_names, save/RestoreV2/shape_and_slices)]]
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the model your defined is somehow different to the one you saved. Try using `saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('your_model_name.meta')` instead of build the graph mannually in `neural_network_model()`.

Comment: I used saver = tf.train.Saver(). Running train_neural_network is now giving me error saying that ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable, check your graph for ops that do not support gradients, between variables .